# Having problems rendering a page using javascript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am completely new to react, and a noob in general when it comes to web development.

I am trying to follow along with this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB7xkRsEq-g&list=TLPQMDMwMTIwMjMzp8A6fEwAdQ&t=1389s the part from 19:15 to 23:11) where an api for chatgpt are being built. From the video, all that is coded is an index.js file:

```js
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const app = express();
 const port = 3001;

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(cors());


 app.post('/', (req, res) => {
     res.json({
         message: "Hello World!"
     });
 });


 app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
 });
```

and an App.js file:

```js
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
 import './App.css';


 function App() {
   const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
   const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     fetch('http://localhost:3001/', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
     })
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then((data) => setResponse(data.message));
   };

   return (
     <div className="App">
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <textarea 
           value={message}
           onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
         ></textarea>
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
       <div>{response}</div>
     </div>
   );
 }
      
export default App
```

However, when running node index.js all I get at localhost:3001 is Cannot GET /, while the dude at youtube gets a submit form and a button. Would be extremely thankful if anybody could enlighten me on why I just get an error, and also how I can make this app render the same as in the youtube video at 23:11?

I have tried making an index.html page connected to the app.js script for rendering, but I cannot seem to get it working. However, I am mostly cursious if the youtube video have actually skipped some steps that are not shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localhost:3001 is where your backend runs. When you are trying to visit localhost:3001, it initiates a GET request to the root route at this URL, `GET /`. Since you have one API route which is `POST /`, you see the message `Cannot GET /`.

You need to visit localhost:3000 (as in the video) where your frontend React server is running to view the form.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! I can now finally sleep, thanks again!